# Search for file and append text to that file using Windows Batch

Tags: windows, file, search, batch-file

I am new to Windows Batch programming. I want to search for a file "names.ini" and append some text at the end of the file.

But the file resides in different locations on different machines.

For instance:

```
C:\EmpInfo\names.ini on Machine A

D:\EmpInfo\names.ini on Machine B

C:\EmpInfo_V1\names.ini  on Machine C
```

I want to create a batch file which can search for that particular file on Drive C and Drive D and append some text at the end of the file.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You would be far better off spending some time standardising, i.e. including in the batch something to move this to a standard location or hosting standard files on a network share.

Answer (score 1):

see `HELP FOR` and try at the command prompt

```
 FOR /R %a in (names.ini) DO @ECHO %a
```

to search in more than one drive, you'll need an outer loop. Something like this...

```
@echo off
for %%d in (C D) do (
  pushd %%d:\
  for /r %%f in (names.ini) do (
    echo %%f
  )
  popd
)
```

Comment: +1 but yuck. This could take ages. If would probably be better to break the loop if you find it.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer!!

Below is my final code. It is slow but works fine.

@echo off
for %%d in (C D) do (
  pushd %%d:\
  for /r %%f in (names.ini) do (
  if exist %%f (
    echo %%f  
 echo John>> %%f
 echo Doe>> %%f
  )
  popd
)
)